# On Mouse Hover Show Div with Dynamic Data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have a page with dynamic content on it
i want it to work like whenever mouseover that dynamic data content the information about that content will show in a div

i have done all the coding
but have some bugs in it

the code of dyanmic content where mouseover is working is

fgdfg

the preview of this code is live at

```
fdgfd
```

Mouseover on **ACC** is working

i want it to work on all STOCK SYMBOLS
and the data in mouse over on ACC is not same what it should be

Answer (score 0):

you request code has no param:

```
    **xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q=&tpnt=",true);
    xmlhttp.send();**
```

So it always sends empty request to your ajax data file : getinfo.php
Also, check with console you will find you function **showUser** is undefined, as you never passed any param to it though you defined return on null param. so it never works.

```
    **xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q=<?php echo $sy;?>&tpnt=<?php echo $tpnt;?>",true);
    xmlhttp.send();**
```

pass the q&tpnt param using JS, and store them in Rel in the span, that would make it work fine. php vars **sy** and **tpnt** will not work with ajax.

Please fix this up, and you will get it working.

Comment: the script is working 
but the ACC is showing values of other STOCK
and mouse over is not working on other stocks
it want like the scrolling text on
www.mcxindia.com

Comment: mxcindia has added primary key of record as id to each span, and using 'this' they get the tpnt data value on mouse over. In your code its always a blank request thats why it returns back with null. please refer to their source code using firebug. you will get it.

Comment: You are not passing dynamic data to your querystring, try to pass name or any other data in setUser function from where its called and accordingly retrieve data from getinfo.php based on passed parameter.

Comment: but i am getting tpnt and symbol name on getingo page

Comment: best option to track is create  log file of all the request sent to getinfo file.